# AttributeError - Unable to Access Functions inside File

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, module, attributeerror

While trying to make a library for myself, I get an error stating:

```
module 'r2bpFunctions.functions' has no attribute 'CartesianModel'
```

Where the file i am trying to run is in the same folder as the folder `r2bpFunctions` which holds `functions.py` and the function `CartesianModel` is defined in `functions.py`. Here is a visual representation of my directory:

```
-r2bpFunctions
--functions.py
-file_i_want_to_run
```

I am currently importing the file as:

`import r2bpFunctions.functions as r2bp`

Then, later on in the file I want to run, I have:

`solution = solve_ivp(fun=r2bp.CartesianModel, t_span=tspan, y0=So, method='RK45', rtol=relTol, vectorized=True)`

Why am I unable to see `CartesianModel` inside of `functions`?

Here is the excerpt from `functions` involving `CartesianModel`:

```
import numpy as np

def CartesianModel(t, s):
    u = 398600.44
    # [km^3/s^2] Earth Gravitational Parameter

    R = s[:3]
    # [km] current position vector

    V = s[3:]
    # [km/s] current velocity vector

    Sdot = np.zeros(shape=(6, 1))
    # [] Allocate Memory

    Sdot[:3] = V

    Sdot[3:] = -u * R / (np.linalg.norm(R) ** 3)

    return Sdot
```

I have already attempted many different ways of importing the functions to no avail.

Python 3.9.1 
Visual Studio Code

Comment: Try simply `import functions as r2bp`

Comment: @Kraigolas I get `No module named 'functions'` probably since it's in a different folder

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything, I clicked on Run > Start Debugging and that ran my code with no issues. Not every time I click "Run Python File in Terminal', it runs without a problem. I am not sure why that was the case.